# Thunderbird unread badge on Windows -- show for messages marked as unread

Tags: windows, thunderbird

The taskbar icon of Thunderbird correctly shows the unread count for incoming messages. However, if I manually mark a message as unread, it will not show up on the badge. Can I make it show?
Windows platform.

Here is a screenshot of the icon on the Windows taskbar showing unread count:
[image]

Comment: Marking a message as read/unread for me immediately updates the counts next to the inbox folder name and in the bottom status line. Where is your count that doesn't update?

Comment: On the badge of the taskbar icon

Comment: I don't see anything like that. Perhaps you could add a screenshot that will explain where. Which version of Thunderbird are you using?

Comment: You could try using Birdtray which gives you more control over the tray icon

Comment: @harrymc You won't see it if you are on a linux platform. It is a Windows-only feature.

Comment: I'm on Windows, and a screenshot will help. Are you using some software such as Birdtray?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my original post. I have no Birdtray or additional software. In Settings/Incoming Mails, you need to tick the box for "Show a tray icon"